# JS discord bot is getting error: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, embed, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot, but I'm getting the error:

> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with `.catch()`. (rejection id: 2).

I know something is wrong, but not sure what is it.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 's!verifymsg') {
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
      .setTitle('__**VERIFICACIÓN**__')
      .setColor(0xFF0000)
      .setDescription('¡Para poder ver los demás canales, es necesario que reacciones para verificar! \n- Reacciona con (✅)')
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

If you type s!verifymsg it sends an embed in that same channel containing some text in that same embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this guide (https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/using-embeds-in-messages), shows be that there are a couple things that might be causing it:

1) `new RichEmbed()` should probably be `new Discord.RichEmbed()`. This is what the discord.js documentation shows.

2) `message.channel.send(embed);` should probably be `message.channel.send({embed});`.

Comment: You should probably expand out that last example to {embed: embed}. I dont think many people are familiar with the implicit behavior of wrapping an object in an object. plus a lot of the documentation explicitly uses embed: ...

Comment: @Marie I thought about it but wasn't sure of a good way to tie it back to the original code sample.

Comment: For this you have to understand node.js, in 1) you can do `const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');` or `const Discord = require('discord.js')` for 2) `(embed)` alone should work as it will be handeld internally, obv `{embed}` will also work but `{embed: embed}` too because it renames embed to embed wich in this case doesn't matter but when you do `const ExampleEmbed = new RichEmbed()` you have to do `.send('text ( optional) ', { embed: ExampleEmbed });` or `.send(ExampleEmbed)`

Comment: `.send(embed)` only works in the newer versions of discord.js tho so might do `npm update`